# SharePoint site is not getting sign out

Tags: sharepoint

In my SharePoint site I am not able to sign out. Once I sign out the site it redirects to an empty page. After that I can enter into that site without username and password. It will open using previous logged in user automatically. How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to change the IE settings not to automatically login to intranet sites.

Open Internet Explorer -> Tools - Internet options - > Local intranet Zone - > user Authentication ; Select - prompt For user name and password. this is working for me.

Comment: I found at Internet Options->Security->Local intranet->Custom level, on the bottom of the list.